# Synchronized block on a java Object not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to synchronize a block of code based on String, such that Different threads with same String value should be blocked and executed one after other. But different threads with different String values can execute synchronized block at same time. But how ever when i read i got to know synchronization on String is not a good practice. So what i did is, i created one Java Class with only one property and i used that object for synchronization as below. But i didn't work. It is not blocking synchronized block execution when same objects comes at same time...Can some one suggest solution for this ?

```
SampleDTO sampleDTO = new SampleDTO();
sampleDTO.setClmNumber("someDynamicString");
synchronized (sampleDTO) {

}
```

I have implemented equals and hashCode method also inside SampleDTO .

Comment: Need to see more code.  I notice that `sampleDTO` is not final, so if it ever gets replaced by a different object there goes your synchronization.

Comment: Even after changing SampleDTO to final, it is allowing multiple threads with same objects inside synchronized block at same time. But if i put synchronization on sampleDTO.getClmNumber().interen() then synchronization is working, but that is not good practice.

Comment: Different threads with same string value should contain object references pointing to same object. if threads contain different objects, they will not be synchronised even though the string value of the different objects are same.

Comment: I declared SampleDTO  with private static final, In this case synchronization happening for all threads, It is blocking execution even though object value is having different value. I need synchronization  on Object value.